# What happens if you use LinearRegression with OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'd like to understand what happens under the hood of scikitlearn `OneVsRestClassifier` when we use `LinearRegression` as estimator. Does it create one LinearRegressor per class and apply a softmax function to return an output class? Documentation is not clear in this aspect. Even `fit()` source code seems is clear enough.

Comment: I don't think it expects you to use a LinearRegression as a estimator for a classification problem. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Linear regression is not even a classifier; why should it work with OneVsRest?

Comment: I was considering using OneVsRestClassifier to fit hidden->output weights of a RBFNetwork. I can use LinearRegression for that, and then apply a softmax function to determine the class/target of each sample. That's why i wanted to understand OneVsRestClassifier under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OvR is used for **classification** not for **regression** so using LinearRegression would not work at all.

The *one-versus-the-rest(OvR)* strategy is used for multiclass classification with multiple binary classifiers. Take the MNIST digit dataset as an example where you would want to create a system that can classify the digit images into 10 classes (from 0 to 9) using OvR you would train 10 binary classifiers, one for each digit (a 0-detector, a 1-detector, a 2- detector, and so on). Then when you want to classify an image, you get the decision score from each classifier for that image and you select the class whose classifier outputs the highest score.

Comment: Hello, please take a look in my comment on the answer above. Thank you!